# navigation bar with checkbox input for mobile responsiveness not working

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have made this simple portfolio website for a starting project in html and css and i cant seem to make the responsive navigation bar open through the checkbox input. This is a two to three page website and i have the separate code for every page.
(this is my first time using stack overflow so i dont know where to put the code)
HELP would be highly appreciated.

HTML CODE---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet'>
    <title>JUST GODDAMN WORK</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <nav>
        
        <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
            <input type="checkbox" id="check" role="button">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </label>
        <h1 class="logo">
            GRAPHICAL STUDIOS
        </h1>
        <div class="nav-links">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
    <div class="image">
        <img class="main-image"  src="7510724.png" alt="">
        <h1 class="heading">
            DESIGNS THAT FEAL<br>
            AS GOOD AS THEY<br>
            LOOK
        </h1>
        <p>WE MAKE THE DESIGNS THAT STAND OUT TO THE AUDIENCE WHICH IN TURN HELP YOUR BRAND GROW!
           IF YOU ARE IN NEED OF ANY TYPE OF DESIGN, FEEL FREE TO CONTACT US ON FIVERR.WE MAKE THE DESIGNS THAT STAND OUT TO THE AUDIENCE WHICH IN TURN HELP YOUR BRAND GROW!
           IF YOU ARE IN NEED OF ANY TYPE OF DESIGN, FEEL FREE TO CONTACT US ON FIVERR.
        </p>
        <a class="button" href="https://www.fiverr.com/studio6graphic">
            CONTACT NOW!
        </a>
    
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS STYLE SHEET CODE----

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
nav{
    height: 6cqw;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FCCE29;
    align-items: center;
}
.logo{
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3cqw;
    font-weight: 1000;
    color: aliceblue;
    padding-top: 1.2vw ;
    margin-left: 2vw;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
a{
    color: aliceblue;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: none;
}
ul{
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: -2.5vw;
    column-gap: 2vw;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    font-weight: 600;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
    position: static;

}
nav li a:hover{
    background-color: #ffab35;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.main-image{
    display: flex;
    float: right;
    max-width: 60vw;
    margin-top: 10vw;
    position: relative;
}
@media screen and (max-width:660px){
    .main-image{
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        float: none;
        margin-left: 5vw;
        margin-right: 5vw;
        margin-top: 10vw;
        margin-bottom: -20vw;
        max-width: 80vw;
    }
}


.image{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.heading{
    font-family: "Oswald";
    font-weight: 900px;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin-left: 5vw;
    margin-right: 5vw;
    margin-top: 115px;
    line-height: 85px;
}
p{
    font-family: "Oswald";
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 5vw;
    margin-right: 5vw;
    font-size: 15PX;
}
.button{
    margin-top: 60px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
    font-family: "Oswald";
    display: flex;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5vw;
    text-align: center;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 6vh;
    width: 17vh;;
    border: #FCCE29;
    background-color: #FCCE29;
}

.img-one{
    width: 35vw;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 200px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    display: flex;
    float: left;
    justify-content: center;
    align-self: center;
}
.img-two{
    width: 35vw;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 200px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    display: flex;
    float: right;
    justify-content: center;
    align-self: center;
}
.checkbtn{
    display: none;
}
#check{
    display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width:796px) {
    #check{
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .checkbtn{
        display: block;
        font-size: 2vw;
        margin-left: 2vw;
        color: #fff;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 2vw;
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 2vw;
        cursor: pointer;
    }  
    ul {
        margin-top: -8vw;
        position: absolute;
        left: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 3vh;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        top: 60px;
        background-color: #eec533;
        transition: all .5s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you restructure your HTML a bit, and add the missing `</div>` for nav-links, you can use Pure CSS to accomplish this.

After moving the checkbox outside of the label, this allows for the use of the tilde and checked pseudo class.

Tilde represents NEXT child of the parent.

So **#check:checked ~ label ~ .logo ~ .nav-links** means, when the checkbox is checked, the next label, then then next logo, then the next nav-links would have the CSS applied.

```css
.nav-links {
  display: none
}

#check:checked ~ label ~ .logo ~ .nav-links {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>

  <input type="checkbox" id="check" role="button">
  <label for="check" class="checkbtn"><i class="fa fa-bars">BARS</i></label>
  <h1 class="logo">
    GRAPHICAL STUDIOS
  </h1>
  <div class="nav-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Or you can keep your HTML the same (but still add the missing /div. But use the :has on the label.

So `.checkbtn:has(:checked) ~ .logo ~ .nav-links {` would be: if the checkbtn has a child that is checked, then the next logo then the next nav-links apply the CSS

```css
.nav-links {
  display: none
}

.checkbtn:has(:checked) ~ .logo ~ .nav-links {
 display: block
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check" role="button">
  <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></label>
  <h1 class="logo">
    GRAPHICAL STUDIOS
  </h1>
  <div class="nav-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: The tilde is not the "next" sibling but matches the following children. "The general sibling combinator (~) separates two selectors and matches all iterations of the second element, that are following the first element (though not necessarily immediately), and are children of the same parent element." `#check:checked ~ .nav-links` is sufficient.